# Why does liver wrap around inferior vena cava?

Tags: liver, circulatory-system, veins

[image: Liver wrapping around inferior vena cava]

As shown in the image, the liver wraps around inferior vena cava, which takes blood from liver via hepatic veins. Is there an advantage of having the inferior vena cava closer to the liver rather than abdominal aorta? I am guessing it has to do with lower blood pressure in the veins, but I want to check.

It could also be evolutionary thing that has no reason for such structure, but that wrapping around structure seems to have a purpose.

Comment: Nice image, where'd you get that from? ;) I don't know much about this, so my guess would be that hepatic portal vein joins in to vena cava after leaving the liver, so the liver forms such structure around inferior vena cava instead of abdominal aorta.

Comment: I got took a screenshot from this website: http://www.healthline.com/human-body-maps/hepatic-veins.

Also about your point, there are also arteries flowing to the liver from abdominal aorta, so I can imagine liver wrapping around the abdominal artery as well.

Comment: I get your point. I think it could be that keeping vena cava nearer would be better (maybe to easily transport blood from hepatic portal vein due to its low pressure or some other reason I can't think of) or keeping abdominal aorta at an inch distance wouldn't be any bad or probably it was just a matter of chance ;)

Comment: It is really only a matter of two vessels passing "through" an organ; where they are situated depends entirely on their function. The IVC delivers it's supply to the right side of the heart "through" a right sided organ; the aorta leaves the left side of the heart and so is situated to the left of the IVC. Just makes the most sense anatomically in this case.

Comment: Possibly related to the absence of valves in the hepatic veins